# How spring-cloud-stream Kafka Reactive stream partition assignment working with concurrent processing

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka, reactor-kafka

For example, I configure a topic have 2 partitions, but in my application with 1 instance, I use `Flux.parallel(10)` to consume the message, and it has 1000 message lag on that topic, what will happen?

1. Will it poll 10 messages per time? from 2 partitions or 1 partition?
2. Only poll 2 message and 1 partition each?

I want to know how it works, so I could configure it right with the capability of large throughput and consume sequence

BTW I found this [issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/issues/980), but now answer there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better to use multiple receivers instead.

Using parallel can cause problems with out of order offset commits.

Comment: Thanks Gary, if I don't care about the order, then using parallel is a good choice right? and the answer will be totally poll 10 message from both partition?

Comment: Another question is if I want to use multiple receivers, how to do that in reactive? the concurrency configuration will not take effect on reactive.

Comment: Just create multiple receivers.

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for the reply.
Do you mean add more consumers with same consumer group? As I know that the `concurrency` configuration will not take effect on reactive code like flux

Comment: Yes; multiple `KafkaReceiver`s with the same group.